# how to use onClick in react slick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-slick

I am using `react slick` in my Websites. I have 4 slides. Every Slide, I want a onClick Function to get the value. But When I click on the Slide, I am getting the last value only. I searched Stack Overflow but can't find solutions.

Here's the Code:

```
const productSlideImg = [
  { Img: prodImg1, ImgName: "img1", pageLink: "/home" },
  { Img: prodImg2, ImgName: "img2", pageLink: "/about" },
  { Img: prodImg3, ImgName: "img3", pageLink: "/contact" }
];


const handleClickSlide = (item) => {
    console.log(item); // getting "img3" only on every slide click

  };


<Slider
    autoplay={true}
    slidesToShow={1}
    slidesToScroll={1} >

            {productSlideImg.map((item, index) => (
              <div   >
                <img
                  style={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
                  width={"100%"}
                  src={item.Img}
                  onClick={() => {handleClickSlide(item.ImgName) }}
                 
                />
              </div>
            ))}

          </Slider>
```

Please help me with some solutions

Comment: you have a mistake on code, I think you are checking a wrong point of code, you define `handleClickProduts` function on code but you use `handleClickSlide` on `onClick` event!!

Answer (score 1):

you have created a different function handleClickProduts
and using different function on img onClick

```
onClick={() => {handleClickProduts (item.ImgName) }}
```

CodeBox link: [working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-forked-gskmqr?file=/index.js)

Comment: Its a  typo mistake. I have corrected that

Comment: i have just updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution hope the person reading this finds this helpful.
So I was using fade=true in react slick props settings removing that **RESOLVED** the issue for me.
[See Attached Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiF0J.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that when you use `array.map` in react you need to add the key attribute.
So in your case, you need to add the key in your div like this:

```
   <Slider autoplay={true} slidesToShow={1} slidesToScroll={1}>
    {productSlideImg.map((item, index) => (
      // adding the key attribute
      <div key={index}>
        <img
          style={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
          width={"100%"}
          src={item.Img}
          onClick={() => {
            handleClickSlide(item.ImgName);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  </Slider>;
```